# Changing starting number of id column doesn't work

Tags: mysql

I simply want to change my id column to start from 501 instead of 1.

`ALTER TABLE tbl_name AUTO_INCREMENT = 500;` gives me no errors but id still starts from 1. I'm using mysql 5.6.

And if I try to MODIFY my id column the same way, it gives me an error.

Solution: `UPDATE tbl_name SET id = id+500;`

Comment: Your command only works for new inserted values. Already existing values will not changed

Comment: This should work. But maybe your inserts contain a value for the autoincrement column?

Comment: I see, is there any way to change values?

Comment: DO NOT MESS WITH THE AUTO INCREMENT VALUES

Comment: You can change the auto increment values. Should be no problem. As long as it's higher then the highest existing value.

Comment: @Chumppe Have you checked, that after your update you can add new rows?